# What is the correct way to format SPGridView values being displayed?

Tags: sharepoint, formatting, spgridview

### Problem

As we know, SharePoint saves data in database in plain text. Some fields even have concatenated strings like `<id>;#<value>` for user fields. Percents are saved as doubles (1.00000000000000 for 100%) and etc.

Ofcourse, I want to display data as they are displayed in lists.

### What should I do?

Should I use derived SPBoundField to format values (Which I actually did and it works fine until you want to filter (probably SPBoundField won't format me values because i use ObjectDataSource not list and with reflector I saw if there are SPListItems in datasource, then it formats correctly. Not my case)

[alt text http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/2797/ss20090820110331.png](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/2797/ss20090820110331.png)

Or must I loop through all the DataTable and format each row accordingly?

What are Your techniques?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, i did have not know any other solution to loop through DataTable rows and format them accordingly.

If your SPGridView's data source is list, try out [SPBoundField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spboundfield.aspx).

Comment: I have the same problem, tried using SPBoundField, but I'm still getting the "ID;#" prepended.

Answer (score 2):

I normaly use ItemTemplates that inherit from ITemplate. With in the ItemTemplate I use the SPFieldxxxValue classes or some custom formating code. This saves looping through the DataTable and the ItemTemplates can be reused.

The ItemTemplates are attached in Column Binding 
E.G

```
// Normal Data Binding
SPBoundField fld = new SPBoundField();
fld.HeaderText = field.DisplayName;
fld.DataField = field.InternalName;
fld.SortExpression = field.InternalName;
grid.Columns.Add(fld);

// ItemTemplate Binding
TemplateField fld = new TemplateField();
fld.HeaderText = field.DisplayName;
fld.ItemTemplate = new CustomItemTemplateClass(field.InternalName);
fld.SortExpression = field.InternalName;
grid.Columns.Add(fld);
```

An example of a ItemTemplate

```
public class CustomItemTemplateClass : ITemplate
{
    private string FieldName
    { get; set; }

    public CustomItemTemplateClass(string fieldName, string formatString)
    {
        FieldName = fieldName;
    }

    #region ITemplate Members

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        Literal lit = new Literal();
        lit.DataBinding += new EventHandler(lit_DataBinding);
        container.Controls.Add(lit);
    }
    #endregion

    void lit_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Literal lit = (Literal)sender;
        SPGridViewRow container = (SPGridViewRow)lit.NamingContainer;
        string fieldValue = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[FieldName].ToString();

        //Prosses Filed value here
        SPFieldLookupValue lookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(fieldValue);

        //Display new value
        lit.Text = lookupValue.LookupValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, tried it, however when filtering, it still displays raw values from database. I`ll probably format datatable.

Comment: I would like to thank you for posting this code, it saved me a lot of time! It's the clearest example of using Data Binding and ItemTemplate Binding I have found over the Internet in an hour!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved this issue.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Campaign Members">
  <ItemTemplate> 
   <%# RemoveCharacters(Eval("CampaignMembers").ToString())%>
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField> 

// Make sure declare using System.Text.RegularExpression;
protected string RemoveCharacters(object String) 
{
  string s1 = String.ToString(); 
  string newString = Regex.Replace(s1, @"#[\d-];", string.Empty); 
  newString = Regex.Replace(newString, "#", " "); 
  return newString.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options. I don't know the output of all of them (would be a good blog post) but one of them should do what you want:

- [SPListItem.GetFormattedValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.getformattedvalue.aspx)
- [SPField.GetFieldValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalue.aspx)
- [SPField.GetFieldValueAsHtml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalueashtml.aspx)
- [SPField.GetFieldValueAsText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalueastext.aspx)

It may also be handy to know that if you ever want to make use of the raw values then have a look at the `SPField*XYZ*Value` classes. For example the form `<id>;#<value>` you mention is represented by the class SPFieldUserValue. You can pass the [raw text to its constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458798.aspx) and extract the [ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvalue.lookupid.aspx), [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservalue.lookupvalue.aspx), and most usefully [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservalue.user.aspx) very easily.

Comment: I`v tried getter functions, it formats output nicely, however it does not show formatted values in filter dropdown.

Comment: Ah OK. I can't see your image due to a firewall blocking it at my end. In that case you will probably need to 'pre-process' the values. Maybe use the DataBinding event?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either to format the values before binding them to the spgridview. Linq and an anonymous type is preffered or to call a code behind function on the field that needs the formatting upon binding.

```
DataField='<%# FormatUserField(Eval("UserFieldName")) %>'
```

or...maybe a templated field?

Comment: I`m wondering if i can use SPField's somehow? They have the logic inside, but i`m wondering if i can somehow let them do the job and just put them on gridview?